# Show that for two vector spaces, $dF_p(X) = \lim_{t\to 0}(F(p+tX)-F(p))/t$.

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds, differential, pushforward

Let $F : M\to N$ be a map between manifolds. By definition the pushforward of a derivation $X$ in $p$ is $$dF_p(X)(f)=X(f\circ F)$$. Now if $M$ and $N$ are vector spaces, is it true that maybe under some identification, we have $dF_p(X) = \lim_{t\to 0}(F(p+tX)-F(p))/t$ (i.e. the directionnal derivative) ?

I don't really get how to show this. I wan't to show this because it because it seems more easy to handle in practical calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you've written *is* the identification, more or less.

For a finite dimensional real vector space $V$, there is a canonical isomorphism $l_v:V\to T_vV$ for each $v\in V$. Since it maps vectors onto derivations based at $v$, we can define it by defining how $l_v(u)$ acts on a smooth function $f\in C^\infty V$:
$$
l_v(u)f=\frac{d}{dt}f(v+tu)|_{t=0}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(v+tu)-f(v)}{t}
$$
This is precisely the identification one uses when taking directional derivatives in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In fact, more or less all of multivariable calculus can be rephrased in the language of manifolds by composing with these isomorphisms in order to describe everything in terms of the underlying vector space(s).

For a smooth map $F:U\to V$, the expression you've written down is precisely $l_{F(u)}^{-1}\circ d_uF\circ l_u:U\to V$.

Comment: Thank you. I am having a hard time proving it is the same though. I have to show $l_{F(u)}^{-1}\circ d_uF\circ l_u=T_u$, where $T_u(v) = \lim_{t\to 0} (F(u+tv)-F(u))/t$ right? But how do you prove this?

Comment: $l_u(v)\in T_u U$ so $d_u F(l_u(v))(f)=l_u(v)(f\circ F)=\lim_{t\to 0} (f\circ F(u+tv)-f\circ F(u))/t$

Comment: But on the other side : $l_{F(u)}(T_u(v))(f)=\lim_{t \to 0}(f(F(u)+tT_u(v))-f(F(u))/t$ which is not the same no?

Comment: Only one more step: Note that$$F(u+tv)=F(u)+tT_u(v)+R(tv)$$where the remainder term $R(tv)$ satisfies$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{R(tv)}{t}=0$$qualitatively speaking, $F$ agrees with its 1st order Taylor expansion about $u$ up to linear order.

Comment: Using your result, I get $\lim_{t→0}(f∘F(u+tv)−f∘F(u))/t = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(F(u)+tT_u(v)+R(t))-f\circ F(u)}{t}$ but I feel like I am missing something to conclude. I know I need to use the limit $\lim_{t\to 0} R(t)/t=0$ to conclude but I am not sure how

Comment: One way is to use that $f$ is locally Lipschitz: restricting to a sufficiently small neighborhood of $u$, there is a $K\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(w+\delta)-f(w)<K\|\delta\|$, so$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(F(u)+tT_u(v)+R(tv))-f(F(u)+tT_u(v))}{t}=0$$In hindsight, it would probably be more straightforward to show the equivalence using the coordinates induced by a basis for $U$ and $V$.

Comment: Okay, I just tried expressing in coordinates. Then it seems more easy.